# Ubuntu 18.04 : Blank out Issue with 2nd external screen

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 in my dell laptop and I have connected it to a wavelike dock which support two HDMI ports for external screens.I am using two external screen of dell P2219H,  1st screen works perfectly, but second screen is blank out. following is the [Output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fcYx4ZC9Pg/) of "Xrandr" command :

Following is the display screen output :

[image]

thanks,
robin